# Login form implemented with Amplify is not applied styling

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I asked same question in Japanese forum and no answer was returned so that I am asiking in this site.

This question is about AWS Amplify.

I am trying to implement login form with React and withAuthenticator() of Amplify in reference to a document of AWS(https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication) , 
but my login form is not like sample's UI of the document and css is not applied like this below image.

I can login and signup.

Is there anything to resolve this problem?

[my login form made by withAuthenticator()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNdPO.png)

```
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

function App() {
  return (

  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

I cleared cache but not working.

Also there are no errors in the development tool of Chrome.

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 9):

Try using `@aws-amplify/ui-react` instead of `aws-amplify-react`.

```
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
```

Comment: For documentation on the `@aws-amplify/ui-react` package, see: 
https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/getting-started/installation

Answer (score 6):

In your app.js add the following inport

```
import '@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css';
```

Comment: This worked for me and I am using 'was-amplify-react'

Comment: Please note that the `aws-amplify-react` package is no longer supported. For instructions on using the new `@aws-amplify/ui-react` package, see:
https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/getting-started/installation

Answer (score 4):

Only this one worked for me:

```
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
```

Answer (score 2):

I was missing this import

```
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
```